# Pie Chart - Shadow

Tags: css, mvvm, kendo-ui, pie-chart

Can I get a pie Chart with shadow like this attached image?

[image]

If yes, how?

This is the code of pie chart:

```
 <div data-role="chart"
         data-title="{ text: 'PieChart', position: 'bottom' }"
         data-series-defaults="{ type: 'pie' }"
         data-series="[{
                         field: 'value',
                         categoryField: 'name',
                         padding: 0,
                         labels: {visible: true}
                      }]"
         data-bind="source: listPieChart,
         events: { seriesHover: onSeriesHoverPieChart }">
</div>
```

Comment: To whoever down-voted this question, unless you state what the problem is, your gesture means nothing.

Comment: I want to create a shadow on the pie chart  as in the image
So the pie looks up

Comment: I'm sorry that the question is not clear to others
  It seems pretty clear

Comment: I don't know why it was down-voted either...

Comment: For dislike or disgrace I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Kendo UI Pie Chart doesn't support any 3D elements. You can read about it in the Telerik forums [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/charts-in-3d).

You have 3 options:

1. Give up on the 3D look.
2. Implement some effect yourself using CSS. This could be quite tricky.
3. Go for another Pie Chart solution, not part of the Kendo UI.

Comment: I will analyze your answer calmly and make a decision.
I think I will implement a css page